# How do you prevent specific class scripts from transfering to all classes?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I just started scripting and have a bunch for spy (to modify the cursor, remove view model, modify sensitivity, rebind keys, etc.).  How do I prevent scripts in the `spy.cfg` class file from spreading to all my other classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot prevent this due to the way .cfg files work.

What you can do is, if a setting appears in at least one class, write the default setting to all the other class config files.

To go a step further, make a .cfg file with all those default settings and execute it at the beginning of each class config file. No further hacks will be required.

Comment: "make a .cfg file with all those default settings and execute it at the beginning of each class config file" how do you go about doing this?

Comment: To execute a cfg file from within another cfg file in the same directory, use the exec command: exec some_other_file.cfg

Comment: exelent ty, do you happen to no the defaoult cursor in tf2 it says none is there a specific command or is this not possible?

Comment: You don't give any exact information how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 6):

**The Solution:**

Make a script for each class, and place `exec config.cfg` at the top of each one.

This config file contains all your default settings, and should clear any key bindings and other assorted changes.

This should unclutter your scripts quite a bit.

---

**Important Note:**

Any excessively strange settings you may have created that aren't in the 'default' setup of TF2 may not be undone by this, so you may have to include your own code to undo them.

If this is the case, make a separate config file and place the code to clear them in that file. Then, simply place `exec <custom reset script name>.cfg` before `exec config.cfg` in each class script.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `exec reset` command instead? `reset.cfg` file has to be created first.

Answer (score 4):

Create `reset.cfg` file in  `~\Team Fortress 2\tf\cfg`, it resets all the values you change in your various class configs.

Then, add `exec reset.cfg` as the top line to all 9 class config files:

- `scout.cfg`
- `pyro.cfg`
- `soldier.cfg`
- `demoman.cfg`
- `heavyweapons.cfg`
- `engineer.cfg`
- `medic.cfg`
- `spy.cfg`
- `sniper.cfg`

Comment: Can you send a link or something that has like a reset config or something?

Comment: @sKantei: What do you mean? Create reset.cfg file in `~\Team Fortress 2\tf\cfg`.